# focus custom text input when navigate to screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom text input with forwardRef, and useimperativehandle with onFocus.

```
const SearchBar = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('');
const textInputRef = useRef();

React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getText: () => searchQuery,
    onFocus: () => textInputRef.current?.focus(),
}));
```

and I got a search screen that uses this custom text input, and I want when someone navigates from the home screen to auto-focus the custom input
It does not work from the navigation but from the button inside the search screen.

that's my code doesn't work.

```
HomeScreen({navigation}) =>
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Search")} />
```

---

```
SearchScreen({navigation}) =>

    const focusInput = navigation.getParam('focusInput', false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (focusInput) {
             searchInputRef.current?.onFocus();
        }
    }, [focusInput]);
   return (
     <CustomTextInput ref={searchInputRef} />
```

using React-navigation v4

Comment: Try changing the useEffect's dependency to `focusInput.current`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that doesnt work. but I see that after the the search screen rerender after navigate it does open. so its something from the deps

Comment: Sometimes this happens when an event is called too fast. Try placing your `focus` call inside a `setTimeout` with a slight delay.